# How to run tornado fx hello world with java 7

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I've been trying to run the following example from youtube with no success, first it couldn't load javafx on class path so I added it manually, but right now it says that it can't find `main` method beside fact, that author could run it without main method.

Also, installing tornado fx plugin and creating project from template throws the same error.

I believe it is related to java 7 and no usage of javafx package tool.

**LoginScreen.kt**

```
class LoginScreen : View() {
    override  val root = VBox()

    init {
        with (root) {
            hbox {
                label("Username")
                textfield()
            }

            hbox {
                label("Password")
                passwordfield()
            }

            hbox {
                button("Login")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyApp.kt**

```
class MyApp : App() {
    override val primaryView = LoginScreen::class
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe TornadoFX requires a minimum of Java 8 to work. It needs the JavaFX in the Java 8 standard library.

Answer (score 1):

To run a TornadoFX application use an "Application" configuration in IDE. More on that in the docs: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/wiki/Application-Startup